# How to get the value from sqf:user-entry?

Tags: schematron, schematron-quickfix

I want to get two integers from the user when the user tries to apply a quick fix using schematron rules and use the values as variables in the replace operation. But I get the error saying "variable has not been declared"

I have this schematron rule that finds the first empty choice element in a step and prompts the user to apply a quick fix. When the user applies the quick fix, a dialog box appears and prompts the user to provide two integers. The user input will be used to calculate a range of step elements.

### The schematron rule

```
<sch:rule context="choice[1][not(normalize-space())]">
            <sch:assert test="choice[1][not(normalize-space())]" sqf:fix='editchoice'>great
            </sch:assert>
     
</sch:rule>
```

### the fix

```
 <sqf:fix id="editchoice">
          <sqf:description>
              <sqf:title>Enter the last step number</sqf:title>
          </sqf:description>
          
          <sqf:user-entry name="step1" type="xs:integer" >
              <sqf:description>
                  <sqf:title>Enter the first step to be converted to choice</sqf:title>
              </sqf:description>
          </sqf:user-entry>
          
          <sqf:user-entry name="laststep" type="xs:integer">
              <sqf:description>
                  <sqf:title>Enter the last step to be converted</sqf:title>
              </sqf:description>
              
          </sqf:user-entry>
           
          <sqf:replace match="./ancestor::steps/step[position()>$step1 and not(position()>=$laststep)]" target='choice' node-type='keep'></sqf:replace>
          
      </sqf:fix>
```

### The expected result

$step1 and $laststep should be replaced with the userinput values.

### actual result

Variable step1 has not been declared (or its declaration is not in scope)

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no implementation which supports the usage of user entries in the `match` attribute (I'm working on that...).

Meanwhile you have to do this:

```xml
<sqf:replace match="./ancestor::steps/step">
    <sch:let name="pos" value="count(preceding-sibling::step) + 1"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$pos > number($step1) and not($pos >= number($laststep))">
            <choice/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <sqf:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</sqf:replace>
```

**Note**: you need the `number()` because the Oxygen nativ implementation does not support the `type` of user-entry yet.